# Countdown alway with two numbers eg: 02:20:02

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Hello i have a problem with this code. I have tried several ways but without a success to get zero before hours etc. Also I checked different topics but without a success.

```
var timestamp = (Date.now() + 1000 * 2 * 60 * 24 * 1) - Date.now();
timestamp /= 1000;

function component(x, v) {
  return Math.floor(x / v);
}

/* last thing i tried but maybe it will help someone
 Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
 var s = String(this);
 while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
 return s;
 };
*/

var $div = $('div');

setInterval(function () {
  timestamp--;

  var
    hours = component(timestamp, 60 * 60),
    minutes = component(timestamp, 60) % 60,
    seconds = component(timestamp, 1) % 60;

  $div.html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}, 1000);
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/5z7ahmze/1/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5z7ahmze/2/  you will need to check if the value if < 10 and add a 0 `(hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours`

Comment: I think you want everything in double digit right? Like if the time comes 20 mins it display 12:20:12 and also for 02 mins 12:02:12.

Comment: not everything because i dont have days therefore the hours can be in three digits... but i have already the answer thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check your variable and add a 0 before if needed :

```
var comp = component(timestamp, 60 * 60);
var hour = comp < 10 ? '0' + comp : comp;
```

Comment: You forgot the minutes and the seconds, bro. Imagine 05:3:6. That is wrong. You need a method to add the 0 to every number lesser than 10. Like i did.

Comment: I guess @Joe is able to replicate this kind of logic on his own.

Comment: I'm not saying this. But a good logic is reusable, not replicable. Just saying.

Comment: I think this answer is still the best... Thank you Cubi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is what you want. Right?

### EDIT

Ok, the final answer.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {

    timestamp--;

    function addZero (number) {
        var zeroedNumber = (number < 10) ? 0 + "" + number : number;
        return zeroedNumber;
    }

    var
    hours = addZero(component(timestamp, 60 * 60)),
    minutes = addZero(component(timestamp, 60) % 60),
    seconds = addZero(component(timestamp, 1) % 60);


    $div.html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

    //Below, i helped you with a "stop count" handler. (:
    if(hours == 0 & minutes == 0 & seconds == 1){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

}, 1000);
```

Dinamically dding zeroes to your counter if (hour or minute or second) is < 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can  create a function like this

```
function pad(number, length) {
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
}
```

and then

```
$div.html(pad(hours, 2) + ":" + pad(minutes, 2) + ":" + pad(seconds, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is working, if you call the pad function on the numbers:

```
$div.html(hours.pad() + ":" + minutes.pad() + ":" + seconds.pad());
```